# SSRS unusual Pagebreak in a long text

Tags: ssrs-2008, page-break

i am creating a report for SQL Server 2008.
i have a table with some rows. One of the row has a long text which will be displayed. If the text has a certain length, the whole row will be displayed on the second page and the half of the first page is empty.
If the text is a bit shorter, the text will be displayed correctly on the first page.
If the text is a bit longer, the text will also be displayed correctly (the first part of the text on the first page, the second part on the second page).

I cant find any settings for this problem.
Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the `Keep together on one page if possible` setting at the **Tablix** level.

You can also look at the `KeepTogether` property at the row level and at other levels, e.g. Group.

Another option is to insert any objects to be kept together in a parent **Rectangle** object; this will always keep items together where possible.